# How to display 100K XML based DOM data on a JSP client page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsp, dom

I need some help in understanding what to do next.

I need to write a web based search function to find medical records from an XML file.
The operator can enter either part or all of a patient name and Hit Search on the JSP web page.

The server is suppose to then return a list of possible patient names with the opportunity for the operator to go to next page until a possible patient is found. They can then select the person and view more details.

On the Server side

I have an XML file with about 100,000 records. There are five different types of records in the file. (This is roughly about 20,000 x 5 = 100,000).

I have a java class to source the xml file and create a DOM to traverse the data elements found on the file.

-- XML File Begin

```
100k - XML file outline

<hospital>
<infant key="infant/0002DC15" diagtype="general entry" mdate="2015-02-18">
<patient>James Holt</patient>
<physician>Michael Cheng</physician>
<physician>David Long</physician>
<diagnosisCode>IDC9</diagnosisCode>
..
</infant>

<injury key="injury/0002IC15" diagtype="general entry" mdate="2015-03-14">
<patient>Sara Lee</patient>
<physician>Michael Cheng</physician>
<diagnosisCode>IEC9</diagnosisCode>
..
</injury>

<terminal key="terminal/00X2IC15" diagtype="terminal entry" mdate="2015-05-14">
<patient>Jason Man</patient>
<physician>John Hoskin</physician>
<diagnosisCode>FEC9</diagnosisCode>
<diagnosisCode>FXC9</diagnosisCode>
..
</terminal>

<aged key= xxxx ... >
...
</aged>

<sickness key= xxxx ... >
...
</sickness>
</hospital>
```

approx 5 (    )x 20,000 = 100K records.

Key and patient are the only mandatory fields. The rest of the elements are Optional or multiple elements.

-- XML File End

Here is where I need help

Once I have the DOM how do I go forward in letting the client know what was found in the XML file?

Do I create a MAP to hold the element node links and then forward say 50 links at a time to the JSP and then wait to send some more links when the user hits next page?

Is there an automated way of displaying the links, either via a Java Script, Jquery, XSLT or  do I just  create a table in HTML and place patient links inside the rows?  Is there some rendering specific thing I have to do in order to display the data depending on the browser used by client?

Any guidance, tutorials, examples or books I can refer to  would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post a piece of xml (a few lines) as an example?

Comment: Hello lifeisfoo - Post updated with sample XML file as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know an automatic way to match the type in jQuery, but you can test the attributes, something like verify if a non optional attribute in the object is present:

```
// Non optional Infant attribute
if(obj.nonOptionalAttribute) {
    // handle Infant object
}
```

Or you may add an attribute to differentiate the types (something like a String or int attribute to test in your Javascript).

```
if(obj.type == 'infant') {
    // handle Infant object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@John.west,

You can try to bind the XML to a list of objects (something like Injure implements MyXmlNodeMapping, Terminal implements MyXmlNodeMapping, Infant implements MyXmlNodeMapping and go on and have a List) to iterate and search by the value at the back end or you can pass this XML file to a Javascript (if you are using jQuery you can use a get or a post defining the result type as XML) and iterate over the objects to find what the user is trying to find...

Your choice may be based on the preference to use processor time in the server side or in the client side...

Comment: Thanks for the response.The xml file is about 2GB in size. Server side would be the  option at this stage. About the MyXmlNodeMapping x 5  Objects solution. 

I am a beginner in the jQuery/java script arena.

How do I then pass on the Object to jQuery to display each page of possible matches on the client side?
Are there embedded smarts in jQuery to automatically do this sort of thing or do I need to manually set how to display/render the data on the client web page with each GET message?

Is there an example/code you can provide or a reference I can use?